# permission in var/www on ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu-12.04

I was able to access and view the files when i first set it. i then realize that my css sheet was not running so i check the source code in Firefox and realize that i didn't have permission to view this file. so i decided to run a permission on the entire www folder. 
Now im getting a 403 error. i tried changing back the permission but still having the same problem. i tried

```
find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

these didn't work, please help

Comment: So are your files in `/var/www` as suggested in the title or in `/opt/lampp/htdocs`?

Comment: sorry i meant find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo chmod 0777 -R /var/www
```

-R is recursive, I assume that your web files are located in /var/www.

Comment: Then do sudo chmod 0777 /var/www/css/style.css

Comment: i tried creating a php or html file, but when i try to view it i still get a permission error.